# When findFragmentByTag is called on a fragment with setRetainInstance set to true, the same instance is not returned

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a a single activity application with two fragments:

1. A fragment with all the UI;
2. A fragment without a view that has an `AsyncTask` as its member, and `setRetainInstance` set to true.

The goal is to keep the AsyncTask running even after the activity gets destroyed, and reuse it when the application comes back to focus.

I am not using `setTargetFragment`, all communication between fragments is done via the `MainActivity`.

What I thought `setRetainInstance` did is prevent the fragment from being recreated and keep the exact same instance at my disposal, so when I call `findFragmentByTag` when recreating a destroyed activity, it should return the same retained instance as when it got created, but that does not seem to be the case.

The result is that I end up with a noUi fragment that keeps counting in the background (I can see the bastard in the debugger), and another, recreated one that does not have the reference to my running AsyncTask...

What am I doing wrong?

Here's some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
implements FragmentCounter.Callback, FragmentMainScreen.Callback {

private static final String TAG_MAINFRAGMENT = "TAG_MAINFRAGMENT";
private static final String TAG_COUNTERFRAGMENT = "TAG_COUNTERFRAGMENT";
private FragmentMainScreen mFragmentMain;
private FragmentCounter mFragmentCounter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mFragmentMain = FragmentMainScreen.getInstance();
        mFragmentCounter = FragmentCounter.getInstance();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, mFragmentMain, TAG_MAINFRAGMENT)
            .add(mFragmentCounter, TAG_COUNTERFRAGMENT)
            .commit();
    } else {
        mFragmentMain = (FragmentMainScreen) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(TAG_MAINFRAGMENT);
 //The fragment that gets returned here is not the same instance as the one
 //I returned with getInstance() above.
        mFragmentCounter = (FragmentCounter) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(TAG_COUNTERFRAGMENT);
    }
}
}
```

The noGui Fragment:

```
public class FragmentCounter extends Fragment
implements CounterAsyncTask.Callback, FragmentMainScreen.Callback {

private Callback mListener;

private CounterAsyncTask mCounterTask;

public static FragmentCounter getInstance(){
    return new FragmentCounter();
}

public interface Callback {
    public void onData(int aValue);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof Callback)
        mListener = (Callback) activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onValueChanged(int value) {
//In the debugger, I can see this callback beeing called,
//even after my activity gets destroyed.
//The mListener is null since I set it that way in the onDetach to
//prevent memory leaks.
//The new activity has a different instance of this Fragment.
    if (mListener != null)
        mListener.onData(value);
}

@Override
public void startCounting(int from) {
    mCounterTask = new CounterAsyncTask(this);
    mCounterTask.execute(from);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
public class CounterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>{

private int counter;
private Callback mListener;
private static final int SKIP = 5000;

public CounterAsyncTask(Callback listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer...values) {
    if (values != null)
        counter = values[0];
    while(!this.isCancelled()){
        publishProgress(counter+=SKIP);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(SKIP);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mListener.onValueChanged(values[0]);
}

public interface Callback{
    public void onValueChanged(int value);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. With setRetainInstance the Fragment is retained **only** upon *configuration* change. So the fragment state will be maintained on screen rotation or if the activity is in the background but **not** if the activity gets destroyed.

To achieve the result I wanted I should probably use a Service.